# How to get vi or vi like editor on an android Samsung galaxy tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I'm using an Android Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet, and I downloaded terminal from the market; I want to edit a network host file. However, there does not appear to be a text editor in terminal. Does anyone know how to get vi on the tablet or something similar?

In short, what is the most straight forward way to edit files on the Samsung tab 10.1 Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the busybox version of vi. If you're rooted then you can get it from the Market and it will install pretty trivially ([example](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en)). Then you'd just need to execute `vi` from a terminal and you're good to go. I don't know of any installers that don't require root, but there may be one floating around somewhere that will install to `/data/local` or something.

Alternatively, you can do it the "manual" way. The following should work fine on an unrooted phone:

- Download a busybox binary or build it yourself (the busybox website [hosts ARM binaries](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/) that should work).
- Copy the binary over to `/data/local` somehow. `adb` is easy if you have it set up - just connect your tablet and use: `adb push /path/to/busybox /data/local`. You could also put it on your SD card and then move it with a file manager. You may optionally want to rename it to simply `busybox` (I'll assume this is the case in the next steps).
- You may need to use `chmod` to make it executable, which can be done from either a terminal emulator or an `adb` shell - `chmod 0755 /data/local/busybox` should suffice.
- Execute `vi` from a terminal with `/data/local/busybox vi`.

Of course, if you just want any ol' editor you don't have to use vi. There are a bunch [in the Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=text%20editor&so=1&c=apps).

Comment: Your link to CyanogenMod seems to be outdated.  The `busybox-android` binary from [this github project](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android) seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Android Market has [aVim Editor(Vi/Vim)](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.easyndk.avim&hl=en). It is not free and has some poor reviews.